# Facing Timeout issue while earlier this code was working

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, browser-automation

```
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C://chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe");
          WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
          driver.get("http://qaclickacademy.com/practice.php");
          List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type= 'checkbox']"));
          System.out.println(Integer.toString(elements.size()));

          for(WebElement el:elements)
          {
                el.click();
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try by providing wait statement.

Comment: I have used wait but still the program is going timeout exception.

Comment: Code looks good, providing wait as suggested by Shanila should help, if not please  share the exception stack.

Comment: There could be a potential issue in the click statement as you are performing them in a loop. After performing the initial events, the state of the rest of the elements might be changing. So please be careful while performing webdriver events in loop.

Comment: Probably your browser was updated and you need to update your webdriver?

Comment: Google Chrome is up to date
Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Chrome driver is also updated because I have downloaded on Jan/19/2019.

Comment: Thanks to all of you showing interest in my post
I have resolve the issue only by doing "Clean & Refreshing" the project.